# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Ошибка `FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException` в этой строке

```
 holder.imageArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
```

Как исправить?

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] names;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView firstLine,secondLine;
    public ImageView imageArrow;
}

public MyCustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
    super(context, R.layout.my_item, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item, null);
        // configure view holder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.firstLine = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        viewHolder.secondLine = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        viewHolder.imageArrow = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }


    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    String s = names[position];
    holder.firstLine.setText(s);
    holder.secondLine.setText("number " + (position + 1));

    holder.imageArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: А `R.drawable.arrow` откуда берется?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский своя картинка добавленная в drawable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.к. ошибка вываливается на строке

> holder.imageArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);

а на предыдущих не вываливается, значит `holder.imageArrow == null`

Засим, видать, ошибка у вас в разметке. Или `ImageView` там нет или `id` у неё не тот, по коему вы ищете его в коде.